# Google Depedency error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Disclaimer: this is my first crack at Android app development.

I'm trying to integrate Google's Calendar into my app using Google Calendar Android Quickstart as my reference guide. I'm on Step 4 where it's telling me to replace the contents of my app build.gradle with what they have. Seeing that I have most of the content that's displayed on their webpage, I just tried adding the things that I didn't have, which are some of the dependencies.

So, these are my app's current dependencies in the build.gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and these are the dependencies that I'm trying to add into my build.gradle; the dependencies below are from Google Calendar Android Quickstart in Step 4.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev265-1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```

When I add those 4 dependencies from Google's webpage, I end up with the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'. Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.
```

Any ideas as to why I'm getting that error, or any solution(s) to it?

Comment: Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2` is providing  version 2.0.1 of `com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305`

You can solve it by replacing

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

With:

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get this error is, first the instrumented tests in src/androidTest/ source set are shared by all build variants. When building a test APK for the "MyFlavor" variant of your app, Gradle combines both the src/androidTest/ and src/androidTestMyFlavor/ source sets.

For example, the following table shows how instrumentation test files should reside in source sets that correspond to the app's code source sets.

`src/main/java/Foo.java` => `src/androidTest/java/AndroidFooTest.java` `src/myFlavor/java/Foo.java` => `src/androidTestMyFlavor/java/AndroidFooTest.java`

Just as it does for your app source sets, the Gradle build merges and overrides files from different test source sets. In this case, the AndroidFooTest.java file in the "androidTestMyFlavor" source set overrides the version in the "androidTest" source set. For more information about how source sets are merged.

My suggestion is to remove all test dependencies and folders and see build again.
Remove these for first to analyse the real problem first.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```